# Center the node on event/submit and redraw graph?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to learn d3 where I came across this example http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/Bf5nM/light/
How can we redraw the whole graph once the searched node is found? Also if user clicks on any particular node, that node should appear at center and graph should be redrawn based on the position of the node.

I tried doing :

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
     d.x = w / 2;
     d.y = h / 2;
})
```

But didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The searchNode function stops the rest of the graph from drawing by setting its opacity to 0. You can see this in the fiddle, lines 88-110.

You can potentially fade them slightly if you set the opacity to 0.5.

As for the centering, this has some difficulties because of the way the force layout is designed - it will pull things back to their 'stable' position, based on the links to other nodes.

You might try having a look at the sticky force layout [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558), for some ideas on how to glue a node to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Lets say I want to re-position the node on doubleclick and there is a zoom function on doubleclick,

```
var min_zoom = 0.1;
var max_zoom = 7;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([min_zoom,max_zoom]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr(
                "width", width).attr("height", height)
                .call(zoom).append('svg:g');

node.on("dblclick.zoom", function(d) { 

d3.event.stopPropagation(); //prevents zoom behavior on doubleclick
    var dcx = (width/2-d.x*zoom.scale());
    var dcy = (height/2-d.y*zoom.scale());
    zoom.translate([dcx,dcy]);
    svg.attr("transform", "translate("+ dcx + "," + dcy  + ")scale(" + zoom.scale() + ")");

    });
```

Essentially my svg is re-positioned based on the value that I set, in this case the node's x and y position.